# How to separate beamer columns with vertical lines

Tags: beamer, rules, columns

I am using the `columns` environment with `beamer`.

```
\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{dictmat-4.png}
\end{column}
\hspace{-50pt}
\begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{dictmat-5.png}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

How can I draw a vertical line between two columns (i.e., the two figures?)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try adding a `\vrule` between the two columns:

```
\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
\end{column}
\hspace{-50pt}
\vrule{}
\begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

Comment: It worked fine! I just had to remove \hspace and use [T] as parameter to \begin{columns}[T]

Comment: Do you know if this can work with the `\column{.5\textwidth}` syntax (without the `\begin{column}` and `\end{column}` tags)?

Comment: @askewchan I normally use `\column{0.5\textwidth}`, but that didn't work for me when trying to get the line between columns.