# vertical dashed line between columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, columns

How to draw vertical **dashed** line between columns in beamer?

I have found how to make [vertical line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95169/), but not **dashed** :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit hacky, but with the `dashrule` package and `\rotatebox` macro from `graphicx` you can achieve something like the following (MWE taken from the other question you linked):

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\begin{document}
  \begin{columns}[c]
   \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
   \end{column}
   \rotatebox{-90}{\hskip-1.8cm\hdashrule[0.2ex]{5cm}{1pt}{3mm}}
   \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
    \hskip10pt
    \includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
   \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

You need to enclose the `\hdashrule` macro into a rotatebox and manually adjust the starting point of the rule after the rotation with a `\hskip`.

You can control the dashing factor, thickness, length, etc. of the rule via the `\hdashrule` command parameters explained in the package documentation.

### TikZ solution

Just for fun, here is a TikZ based alternative solution:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\vdashrule}[1]{\tikz[remember picture]\draw[dashed,thick,overlay](current page.north)--+(0,-#1);}

\begin{document}
  \begin{columns}[c]
   \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
   \end{column}
    \vdashrule{3.5}
   \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
    \hskip10pt
    \includegraphics<1>[width=0.35\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
   \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

I just defined a `\vdashrule` command that takes advantage of the `overlay` and `remember picture` TikZ options, which let you anchor the rule to frame borders (or everywhere else in the frame, if you like).

The length of the rule is specified with an argument and the style can be controlled via the TikZ options.

The visual result is pretty much the same as the previous screenshot.